# Using a Variable as a Dictionary Key

Tags: swift, dictionary

In the code below I was trying to make a loop that would go through my string and add the value of each character in the string to the total variable.

```
var stringSent = "babbbababa"
let charValues = ["a":1,"b":2]

var total = 0

for i in stringSent.characters{
switch i{
    case "a":
        total += charValues["a"]!
        //adds 1 to total
    case "b":
        total += charValues[i]!
        //throws error
    default:
        print("default was sent")
}
 print(total)
}
```

Initially I was going to use a for loop like so to keep lines to the fewest which I would love to do if I can figure out how to get the variable "i" to correctly be used as a key to retreive the current characters value.

```
for i in stringSent.characters {
    total += charValues[i]
}
```

Am I doing something wrong with my dictionary or is this method not possible? I havent found anything helpful from apple or google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `characters` are Characters but the keys in your dictionary are Strings. So just convert:

```
let stringSent = "babbbababa"
let charValues = ["a":1,"b":2]

var total = 0

for i in stringSent.characters{
    total += charValues[String(i)]!
}
```

Or, go the other way — specify that the keys in the dictionary should be Characters:

```
let stringSent = "babbbababa"
let charValues : [Character:Int] = ["a":1,"b":2]

var total = 0

for i in stringSent.characters{
    total += charValues[i]!
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, I had a feeling they werent the same data types, I tried changing the dictionary to [Character: Int] but I didnt have the "!" so it wouldnt do anything.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to calculate the weighted sum of the characters in the `String` instance `stringSent` (given some known weights for each `Character`). The problem in your own implementation is that you're trying to access the value of a key in your dictionary using a variable that differs from the type of the dictionariy's key (`Character` is not the same as `String`)

> ```
> total += charValues[i]! // 'i' is a Character here
> ```

You could simplify your implementation and likewise avoid making use of the explicit unwrapping (`!`) in several different ways, e.g. applying `reduce` to the `CharacterView` of `stringSent`

```
var stringSent = "babbbababa"
let charValues = ["a": 1, "b": 2]

let total = stringSent.characters.reduce(0) { $0 + (charValues[String($1)] ?? 0) }
// 16
```

---

(With respect to the original misunderstood version of this answer), another (slightly more wasteful) alternative could be to calculate the frequencies of each character in the `String` instance `stringSent`, whereafter the associated weight could be applied to each frequency to compute the total weighted sum.

```
var stringSent = "babbbababa"
let charValues = ["a": 1, "b": 2]

var freqs: [String: Int] = [:]
stringSent.characters.forEach { freqs[String($0)] = (freqs[String($0)] ?? 0) + 1 }
print(freqs) // ["b": 6, "a": 4]

let total = freqs.reduce(0) { (sum, kv) in
    sum + (charValues[kv.key].map { kv.value*$0 } ?? 0) }
// 16
```

Comment: Not familiar with reduce, I will read up on it on apples documentation later. Thanks